# calculating statistic difference between groups of rows with adjacent values

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working on some stepped-wedge analyses, and want a way to calculate the statistic of the difference between adjacent time periods. I've come up with something that works on my toy example, but does anyone know of a more efficient way to go from my inputDT to the desiredOutputDT?

```
library(coin)
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
inputDT = data.table(group = factor(c(rep('g1', times = 30),
                                      rep('g2', times = 30))),
                     step = rep(rep(1:3), each=10, times=2),
                     interventionStep = rep(2:3, each=30),
                     val = c(rnorm(mean = 20, sd = 3, n = 10),
                             rnorm(mean = 25, sd = 3, n = 20),
                             rnorm(mean = 15, sd = 3, n = 20),
                             rnorm(mean = 20, sd = 3, n = 10)))


desiredOutputDT = data.table(group2 = factor(c(rep('g1', times = 2),
                                        rep('g2', times = 2))),
                      step1 = rep(1:2,times = 2))
desiredOutputDT[,step2 := step1 + 1]

for (rowInd in 1:nrow(desiredOutputDT)) {
  g = desiredOutputDT[rowInd,group2]
  s1 = desiredOutputDT[rowInd,step1]
  s2 = desiredOutputDT[rowInd,step2]

  desiredOutputDT[rowInd, stat := as.numeric(statistic(independence_test(val ~ step, inputDT[group == g & (step==step1 | step==step2)])), type="standardized")]

}

> desiredOutputDT
   group2 step1 step2        stat
1:     g1     1     2  3.08815389
2:     g1     2     3 -0.84987412
3:     g2     1     2  0.04336604
4:     g2     2     3  3.17319127
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** One possible approach is to use non-equi join:

```
inputDT[, s:=step]
inputDT[
    desiredOutputDT,
    on=.(group=group2, s>=step1, s<=step2), nomatch=0L, allow.cartesian=TRUE,
    .(stat=statistic(
            independence_test(val ~ step, .SD))[1L]),
    by=.EACHI]
```

**2)** Another approach is to join step1 and step2 separately, rbind the tables and perform the calculations:

```
desiredOutputDT[, c("s1", "s2") := .(step1, step2)]
rbindlist(list(
    inputDT[desiredOutputDT, on=.(group=group2, step=step1)],
    inputDT[desiredOutputDT, on=.(group=group2, step=step2)]))[,
        .(stat=statistic(independence_test(val ~ step, .SD))),
        by=.(group, s1, s2)]
```

You can also create `desiredOutputDT` with

```
desiredOutputDT <- inputDT[, CJ(group2=group, step1=seq(max(step)-1L), unique=TRUE)][, 
    step2 := step1 + 1L]
```